# Strange XML output from Java

Tags: java, xml

Recently I made an app that works without errors. It takes user input from texfields(ID, brand, model, type, price and inStock) and writes it to different datasources. I have an interface with methods that the different datasourceclasses implements. I also use a factory to select the DAO-type. Now for practice purpose I've made another app that has EXACTLY the same code, the only difference is couple of different datatypes, for instance the "price" which is a double. I'm having trouble with XML.

I type in all the textfields and press my "add" button and this is a bit of the errormessage:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at javafx.DAOProduktXMLFile.getProducts(DAOProduktXMLFile.java:137)
at javafx.GUI_Pane$Lyssnare.handle(GUI_Pane.java:167)
```

And my XML turns out like this, ID 1 was there before, it was ID number 2 I was trying to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<produkter>
<produkt id="1">
    <brand>Toyz</brand>
    <model>Firetruck</model>
    <type>Vehichle</type>
    <price>199.0</price>
    <inStock>true</inStock>
</produkt>
<produkt id="2">
<brand>false</brand>
<model/>
<type/>
<price/>
<inStock/>
</produkt>
</produkter>
```

Here's the add-method:

```
@Override
public void add(DTOProduct dtoProduct) {
    doc = getDOMDocument();
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    Element produkt = doc.createElement("produkt");
    product.setAttribute("id", String.valueOf(dtoProduct.id));

    Element brand = doc.createElement("brand");
    brand.setTextContent(dtoProduct.brand);

    Element model = doc.createElement("model");
    brand.setTextContent(dtoProduct.model);

    Element type = doc.createElement("type");
    brand.setTextContent(dtoProduct.type);

    Element price = doc.createElement("price");
    brand.setTextContent(String.valueOf(dtoProduct.price));

    Element inStock = doc.createElement("inStock");
    brand.setTextContent(String.valueOf(dtoProduct.inStock));

    product.appendChild(brand);
    product.appendChild(model);
    product.appendChild(type);
    product.appendChild(price);
    product.appendChild(inStock);
    root.appendChild(produkt);
    writeToXML(doc);
}
```

Get DOM document method:

```
private Document getDOMDocument() {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new File("products.xml"));
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Finally, writeToXML method:

```
private void writeToXML(Document doc) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.com/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("products.xml"));

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAOProduktXMLFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have no clue what's wrong. Like I said, all this code is basically copy-pasted from my other working app and then modified to fit my new datatypes, and it was no problem with textfile, mysql or excel, but XML just don't work!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked the DTOProduct values ?

Comment: "Element **model** = doc.createElement("model");
    **brand**.setTextContent(dtoProduct.model);" - copy & paste error? Second: An empty string is not a valid number, so you might want to check the string value for empty/null before trying to convert to a number.

Comment: @Fildor Ok, I feel like the stupidest person on earth right now! I was indeed a copy paste error I overlooked! After you said it I saw it right away, stupid! Thank you anyway!

Comment: It could be an issue with Locale formats, f.e. in some locales decimal separator could be dot or comma. The same code could be ok or not on different systems.

Comment: "I feel like the stupidest person on earth right now" ... no need for that. Anyone telling you he has never before made that kind of c&p-error, wondering what is wrong and debugging it for hours before someone else pointing him to the mistake is plain out lying.